# Codeigniter Language error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-datamapper

I have added a language file named as license_lang.php.Then i called this in controller by $this->lang->load('license');  .But showing error like "Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/license_lang.php". Any idea?

Comment: because you dont have permissions on this file to read it with php

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/language.html

$this->lang->load('**filename**', '**language**');

> Where **filename** is the name of the file you wish to load (without the
>   file extension), and **language** is the language set containing it (ie,
>   english). If the second parameter is missing, the default language set
>   in your application/config/config.php file will be used.

Have you tried the following?

```
$this->lang->load('license_lang');
```

Hope that helps...